# SRA Toolkit execution problem

Tags: fastq, sratoolkit

I am trying to install SRA Toolkit on MacOS, following all the instructions from NCBI website. It is installed but fastq-dump cannot be executed because "cannot execute binary files". I tried "chmod +x", noah from home-brew to make binary executable on MacOS but fast-dump still cannot be executed. I attached the screenshot of my terminal window. Can anyone help? [image]

Comment: Did you upgrade to Catalina (a bad thing due to no support for any 32bit at all)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run Linux binaries on OSX (or vice versa). Download Mac OSX binaries.